# Why this NameError in IDLE shell?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-idle

```
print('What is your name?')    # ask for their name
myName = input()  
print('It is good to meet you, ' + myName) 
print('The length of your name is:')
print(len(myName))
```

When I run it...

```
What is your name?
>>> bn
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#6>", line 1, in <module>
    bn
NameError: name 'bn' is not defined
```

Version

```
>>> import sys; print(sys.version)
3.9.7 (tags/v3.9.7:1016ef3, Aug 30 2021, 20:19:38) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)]
```

Comment: Can you add more informations.

Comment: Just search for the error message "[python] NameError: name 'bn' is not defined". From what your provided, that error is not reproducible, I'm afraid. As a new user here, please also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Your code posting is not complete.

Comment: my version is python 3. Answer is available for python 2.

Comment: What do you mean? You really shouldn't be using Python2 and your code runs fine in Python3

Comment: print('What is your name?')    # ask for their name
myName = input()  print('It is good to meet you, ' + myName) print('The length of your name is:')
   print(len(myName))
   
What is your name?
>>> bn
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#6>", line 1, in <module>
    bn
NameError: name 'bn' is not defined
>>> import sys; print(sys.version)
3.9.7 (tags/v3.9.7:1016ef3, Aug 30 2021, 20:19:38) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)]

Comment: @MicTest please put all code and tracebacks in the question itself, so that it's properly formatted.

Comment: This looks like a Py2 vs Py3 difference. If you want this to work under Py2, try "raw_input" instead of "input". But you should not be using Py2 anymore...

Comment: @martieau thanks a lot

Comment: So, `>>> bn` looks like you are just entering that as an expression into the REPL, not as input. Note sure why.

Comment: @Gary02127 I am using Py3 and getting the error.

Comment: How, **exactly** are you running this?

Comment: how to write as input??

Comment: running in IDLE shell

Comment: type the code and press enter

Comment: Well, your IDLE is not using Python3

Comment: but version is 3. check it.

Comment: @MicTest - I ran your code from IDLE in Py3.8.10 and Py3.9.7, and it runs fine. It might be something in your environment. Add the print call to show system version right into your code. Don't run it separately.

Comment: No, you need to explain *exactly* how you are running this. And post the full REPL session, after starting a new one

Comment: >>> print('What is your name?')    # ask for their name
myName = input()  import sys; print(sys.version)
What is your name?
>>> hgg
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#11>", line 1, in <module>
    hgg
NameError: name 'hgg' is not defined
>>>

Comment: HOW TO 'Add the print call to show system version right into your code'?

Comment: >>> myName = input('What is your name? ')
What is your name? kkhh
>>> print(myName)
kkhh
>>> print('What is your name?')    # ask for their name
myName = input()
What is your name?
>>> 'hgg'
'hgg'
>>> print('It is good to meet you, ' + myName)
It is good to meet you, kkhh
>>>

Answer (score 1):

> `>>> bn`

This means you typed `bn` on the interpreter shell, not to the previous input function....

You might want to write this instead of printing first

```
myName = input('What is your name? ')
```

---

Your error could also be Python2 related

Example

```sh
$ cat /tmp/app.py
print('What is your name?')    # ask for their name
myName = input()
print('It is good to meet you, ' + myName)
print('The length of your name is:')
print(len(myName))
```

```
$ python2 /tmp/app.py
What is your name?
bn
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/app.py", line 2, in <module>
    myName = input()
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'bn' is not defined
```

```
$ python3 /tmp/app.py
What is your name?
bn
It is good to meet you, bn
The length of your name is:
2
```

If you wanted to use Python2, you need to use `raw_input()` as `input()` implicitly calls `eval()` on the inputted values

Comment: But I have clearly explained my version. It is IDLE shell 3.9.7

Comment: Python 3.9.7 (tags/v3.9.7:1016ef3, Aug 30 2021, 20:19:38) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> print('Hello, world!')
Hello, world!

Comment: Okay great, now type the first two lines from your question there.

Comment: thanks. this works. but my doubt is not cleared.

Comment: >>> myName = input('What is your name? ')
What is your name? kkhh
>>> print(myName)
kkhh

Comment: Doubt about what? As explained, `>>> bn` means you've typed a variable `bn` that doesn't exist

Answer (score 0):

There must be a problem in your environment. You should consider uninstalling Python 2.  But, also, try running this code and tell us what the output is:

```
import sys
print(sys.version[:5])
print('What is your name?')    # ask for their name
myName = input()  
print('It is good to meet you, ' + myName) 
print('The length of your name is:')
print(len(myName))
```

Running this in IDLE from Py3.9, I get the following output:

```
Python 3.9.7 (tags/v3.9.7:1016ef3, Aug 30 2021, 20:19:38) [MSC v.1929
64 bit (AMD64)] on win32 Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or
"license()" for more information.
>>> 
==== RESTART: C:\Users\Gary\Google Drive\Projects\StackOverflow\69651615.py ====
3.9.7
What is your name?
bn
It is good to meet you, bn
The length of your name is: 2
>>>
```

Comment: im running ver 3

Comment: but you altered line number 3 in your code